# How come the community user offers bounties?

Tags: discussion, bounty, community-user

Looking at the profile for the [community user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community?tab=bounties&sort=offered), I see that it has offered a lot of bounties:

> [image: Screenshot]

Also, I saw a banner on a question which said "`This question has an open bounty worth +50 reputation from community`", so it seems that the community user actually *places* bounties on questions.

Why ? How ? Does a robot decide what is a good question worth putting a bounty on ?

Comment: That bounty was an auto-award. Perhaps community "owns" all bounties that weren't manually awarded?

Comment: On the very first one in the list, the original author is deleted, and the revisions show Community as starting the bounty. I assume Community takes bounties that were offered by users who later had their accounts deleted.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET, I recently saw a banner on a question "This has an open bounty worth 50 from community". It seems like the community user actually placed the bounty on the question, not just somehow recieved it. Strange.

Comment: Found a couple posts about this on MSE, the main one (with others as dupes pointing to it) being http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139533/how-does-the-community-user-set-bounties This question on MSE indicates that my first comment was correct, at least to a degree.

Comment: I go with @Kendra, because it is the same case with [accepting answers](http://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community?tab=activity&sort=accepts), where you can easily notice how community user accepts answers on behalf of the deleted users, but how can it specify which one is the correct/ acceptable answer?!

Comment: @Jad Community only gets the acceptance if the OP accepted an answer *before* deleting their account. Otherwise, there is no accepted answer.

Comment: If the user accepted an answer, why would the Community accept it again?

Comment: @Jad Community doesn't accept it again- They take ownership of the accept after the asker has deleted their account. However, this _only_ happens if 1) the asker accepts and answer _and then_ 2) the asker deletes their account and the question meets the criteria to not be deleted on account deletion.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This comes down to account deletion. How this works is a user posts a bounty on a question. Either they award the bounty, or it times out, or during the course of the bounty the bounty placer's account is deleted.

If the bounty placer's account is deleted before the bounty is finished, the banner on the bounty will change the username of the placer to point to the Community user, who takes control of several items from deleted users. If the bounty is awarded by the placer or the bounty times out, and *then* the placer's account is deleted, Community will still take ownership of the bounty to keep from having the bounty orphaned.

For an example of the latter, see [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27103860/how-to-upload-image-from-gallery-to-server) Clearly, the bounty was manually awarded as, if you scroll through the revision history, you can see that it was set for 50 points. The first answer on the question was awarded the full 50 points. This means the placer had to have stuck around long enough to select an answer to manually award the bounty to. This is further confirmed by the asker's comment under the answer stating "grant bounty to you."

The Community user takes ownership of plenty of actions from deleted accounts, such as accepted answers askers have placed before deleting their accounts. This is just another example of what the Community user can take ownership of.

### See Also On MSE: [How Does the Community User Set Bounties?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139533/how-does-the-community-user-set-bounties)