# Can community bot upvote posts?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash, community-user, robots

So, The [community bot](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) has the **I Wish to Subscribe** hat. The  description says

> Upvote 3 questions with the [feature-request] tag on Meta Stack Exchange

Does this mean the bot upvoted some posts?

---

About  suggested duplicate,

[How come the Community diamond user is wearing a hat?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312354/how-come-the-community-diamond-user-is-wearing-a-hat)

This question can be differentiated by the fact that this question deals with "how" the bot earned a specific hat.

Comment: AFAIK, deleted users' votes are transferred to the Community user.

Comment: @AndrewT. Hmm I guess that that is a possibility

Comment: See [How can I delete my account?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/how-can-i-delete-my-account) and [Don't throw away all votes when a user is deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125740/dont-throw-away-all-votes-when-a-user-is-deleted). Both has the text "moved to the Community user" :)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

No, the Community User cannot upvote. But when a user is deleted, in some cases their votes are transferred to the Community User.

See [Cody Gray](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/366904/cody-gray)'s [MSE answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/358666) about the [Warm Welcome](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/357917) hat. And also the [MSE FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19738) [Who is the Community user?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19739):

> Owns up/down votes from [very active deleted users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/user-was-removed).

This way, the Community User can earn the hat and a [mod can set the hat at will](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/312367/11682469).

---

SE dev [Nick Craver](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/135201/nick-craver) about Community User in a [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19738/who-is-the-community-user/19739#comment351111_19739):

> This is going to dissapoint, but *technically* Community is just a constant of -1 in a file somewhere...

Comment: Wow. So the universal constants are Death, Taxes, and Community User?

Comment: @user4581301 Yes, those and of course the answer to the ultimate question of life, the universe, and everything.

Comment: In fact, you can see [on its profile page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) just how many votes the Community user has "cast".

Comment: @CodyGray wow, it even owns a bounty. I didn’t know that this is possible at all.

Comment: @Holger See [How come the community user offers bounties?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/291008/11682469)

Comment: Yes, the transfer of a bounty from a deleted user is plausible. What actually surprised (or confused) me, was the bounty on a deleted question which I thought to be impossible…

Comment: Is that a "Not a Robot" badge on there?!  The AI has slipped by our defenses!

Comment: @DougDawson [Yes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/292637/183280).